# Sum minus with condition use bash and AWK

Tags: bash, awk

I have a text file with format like this :

```
crelimit:300000,sos:300000
crelimit:300000,sos:120000
crelimit:300000,sos:10000
crelimit:300000,sos:400000
crelimit:300000,sos:600000
crelimit:300000,sos:700000
crelimit:100000,sos:800000
crelimit:200000,sos:800000
crelimit:300000,sos:1100000
crelimit:120000,sos:120000
```

I'm writting a script to calculator sum minus of value colum 2 and 4 with conditon as below :

```
 cat ir7_temp.txt|sed 's/:/,/g'|cut -d"," -f2,4|awk 'BEGIN {
     FS=",";
     OFS=",";
   }
    (NR > 0){
     percent = 100 * $2 / $1;
     if (percent <= 20) {
         a["0-20%"] += ($1-$2);
     } else if (percent <= 30) {

         a["21-30%"] += ($1-$2);
     } else if (percent <= 50) {

         a["31-50%"] += ($1-$2);
     } else if (percent <= 60) {

         a["51-60%"] += ($1-$2);
     } else if (percent <= 70) {

         a["61-70%"] += ($1-$2);
     } else if (percent <= 80) {

         a["71-80%"] += ($1-$2);
     } else if (percent <= 90) {

         a["81-90%"] += ($1-$2);
     } else {
         a["91-100%"] += ($1-$2);
     }
 }
 END {
     for (i in a) {
         print i, a[i];
     }
 }'|sort > ir7_temp_resul1.txt
```

but i get the negative values in sum. Can you help check if script is correct ?? or any suggest to write it more simple ??

```
0-20%,9581263517
21-30%,2304516259
31-50%,2684412010
51-60%,571491884
61-70%,503126890
71-80%,223638210
81-90%,144111617
91-100%,-45135696
```

Comment: can you post the desired output?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the third data line is over 100 %.

Comment: I updated the sum values..

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: your penultimate input line brings a lot of negativity...

Answer (score 0):

you can simplify the code a bit

```
$ awk -F[,:] -v OFS=, '{a[int($4/$2)]+=($2-$4)} 
                   END {for(k in a) print k*10"-"(k+1)*10-1"%",a[k]}' file
```

and perhaps combine the first two buckets in post processing.